# Why does a form .submit() work when using jQuery but not when using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, form-submit, getelementbyid

I am eliminating all jQuery from my JavaScript (this was suggested to maximize speed) and have one final problem. The goal is to run the loadData function on submit.

when running my script this works:

```
$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
```

but this doesn't:

```
 clickContainer = document.getElementById('form-container');
 clickContainer.addEventListener('submit', loadData());
```

How do I run my loadData function with the submitted info in vanilla JS?

Full code @ https://github.com/ChaMbuna/Marvel-Map

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `clickContainer.addEventListener('submit', loadData);`. Pass the event listener the function, not what the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to:** Problem Passing a Function to Javascript `addEventListener`

Pass `addEventListener` a function name, not the return value of the function. Do this:

```
clickContainer.addEventListener('submit', loadData);
```

Pass to `addEventListener` the name of the function you want to execute when the *submit* event fires. Immediately appending parenthesis to the function name causes the function to be executed and whatever the function *returns* gets passed to the `addEventListener` method and not the function itself.

An exception to this is if the function `loadData` actually returned a function and you wanted the return function to be executed when *submit* fires. In that case you'd want to execute `loadData` as in `loadData()`. Ah, the beauty of JavaScript.